# Clone a SQL Server Database w/ all new Primary Keys

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

We need to create an automated process for cloning small SQL Server databases, but in the destination database all primary keys should be distinct from the source (we are using UNIQUEIDENTIFIER ids for all primary keys).  We have thousands of databases that all have the same schema, and need to use this "clone" process to create new databases with all non-key data matching, but referential integrity maintained.

Is there an easy way to do this?

**Update - Example:**

Each database has ~250 transactional tables that need to be cloned.  Consider the following simple example of a few tables and their relationships (each table has a UniqueIdentifier primary key = id):

```
location
doctor
  doctor_location (to doctor.id via doctor_id, to location.id via location_id)
patient
  patient_address (to patient.id via patient_id)
  patient_medical_history (to patient.id via patient_id)
  patient_doctor (to patient.id via patient_id, to doctor.id via doctor_id)
  patient_visit (to patient.id via patient_id)
  patient_payment (to patient.id via patient_id)
```

The reason we need to clone the databases is due to offices being bought out or changing ownership (due to partnership changes, this happens relatively frequently).  When this occurs, the tax and insurance information changes for the office.  Legally this requires an entirely new corporate structure, and the financials between offices need to be completely separated.

However, most offices want to maintain all of their patient history, so they opt to "clone" the database.  The new database will be stripped of financial history, but all patient/doctor data will be maintained.  The old database will have all information up to the point of the "clone".

The reason new GUIDs are required is that we consolidate all databases into a single relational database for reporting purposes.  Since all transactional tables have GUIDs, this works great ... except for the cases of the clones.

Our only solution so far has been to dump the database to a text file and search and replace GUIDs.  This is ridiculously time consuming, so were hoping for a better way.

Comment: What type of data are you wanting to bring across, is it mostly lookup data? So you are wanting to clone your database and clone all data as well, or just lookup data? What do you mean by non key data for instance?

Comment: Lookup data isn't as important since it's always the same and we can script that (and it has fixed integer keys).  Transactional data is our main concern.  I'll update the q with an example.

Answer (score 0):

I'd do this by creating a basic restore of the database, and updating all values in the primary key to a new GUID.

To make this automatically update all the foreign keys you need to add constraints to the database with the [CASCADE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188066.aspx) keyword i.e.

```
CREATE TABLE Orders
(

    OrderID uniqueidentifier,
    CustomerID uniqueidentifier REFERENCES Customer(CustomerID) ON UPDATE CASCADE,

etc...
```

Now when you update the Customer table's CustomerID the Order table's CustomerID is updated too.

You can do this to a whole table using a simple update query:

```
UPDATE TABLE Customer SET CustomerID = NewID();
```

You'd need to do this to each table with a uniqueidentifier as it's primary key.

Answer (score 0):

You could create an Integration Services (SSIS) package to do this. You would create the new database in the control flow, then copy the data from the source to the destination using the data flow, which would also replace the GUIDs or make other needed transformations along the way.

If the DBs have a large number of tables, and only a few of them need to be modified, then you might be better off just making a copy of the MDF/LDF files, re-attaching them with a new DB name, and using a script to update the IDs.

The advantage of using SSIS is that it's easier to fully automate. The downside is that it might take a little longer to get things set up.